# shorthand for having multiple edges (from different nodes) to one node with same label

Tags: graphviz, dot

I know I can do something like

```
a -> z [label="XXX"];
b -> z [label="XXX"];
c -> z [label="XXX"];
d -> z [label="XXX"];
```

But is there a way to do something like

```
a,b,c,d -> z [label="XXX"];
```

with same output as the code above? It would really make my dot source simpler :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
{a;b;c;d} -> z [label="XXX"];
```

does what you're looking for.

Comment: But I want the edges share the label, not display one label every edge. How to get it? I cannot find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To reply to your comment, here's how you distribute a label (or color or other attribute) across multiple edges:

```
subgraph
{
    edge [label="Hello"];
    {a,b,c,d} -- z;
}
```